# Why does python 2.4 keep ignoring my exit function?

Tags: python, exit, python-2.4

I've written a script that only runs on version 2.6 or 2.7. I've placed in a safety check to see if another version is installed and to also check if there are any compatible versions available. Here is my code snippet;

```
# !/usr/bin/python

import sys, os, re
from sys import exit

if sys.version[0:3] in ['2.6', '2.7']:
    import subprocess, datetime, os.path, json, urllib2, socket

def python_version():

    version = sys.version[0:3]

    while version not in ['2.6', '2.7']:

        print '\n\nYou\'re using an incompatible version of Python (%s)' % version

        python_installed_version = []

        for files in os.listdir("/usr/bin/"):  # check to see version of python already on the box

            python_version = re.search("(python2(.+?)[6-7]$)", files)

            if python_version:
                python_installed_version.append(python_version.group())

        if python_installed_version:

            print 'Fortunately there are compatible version(s) installed. Try the following command(s): \n\n',

            for version in python_installed_version:
                print 'curl http://script.py  | %s\n' % version

        sys.exit()

python_version()

with p.stdout:

print 'hello'
```

When I run the above in python 2.4 I get this error;

```
  File "<stdin>", line 46
      with p.stdout:
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't understand why the script doesn't exit as soon as it detects that you're using python 2.4 with `sys.exit()`, but instead carries on reading the script and gives the error above where the `with p.stout:` is read.

I have removed the `with p.stdout:` line, and it will work fine, it won't read the `print 'hello'`. I don't know why the `with p.stdout:` is causing the script to break. This works perfectly fine on 2.6 and 2.7.

Any ideas on why python 2.4 will still read the `with p.stdout:` line? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python 2.4 doesn't have the `with` syntax support yet, so the script fails at the parsing stage, rather than at runtime. You can work around that by having some wrapper like:

```
if version_check_ok():
    import actual_app
    actual_app.run()
else:
    ...
```

This way the new files with the new syntax will not be imported/parsed until you know it's safe to do so. You can't move the import above the version check however.

Comment: Is there absolutely no way to avoid having to use two files, the check file and the actual script file? I'm going to be running this script on client boxes and be using curl, really want to have to avoid downloading two files and in order to run the script :(

Comment: @user1165419 You could rewrite your code not to use `with`. It's just a syntax sugar after all. Open / close your resource manually and you're sorted. (just remember about all the exceptions you have to catch)

Comment: I'm curious about importing my script option. I use curl to run my script on a box; `curl http://main_script.py | python`. Is it possible to import a script over the internet? ie. I could do a `curl check_version_script.py` and inside that instead of 'import actual_app` something like `import http://main_script.py` so it's all done over the internet, without having to download any files? This could solve my problem

Comment: @user1165419 Not easily. And it sounds like a terrible idea (especially over plain http), compared to just rewriting the `with` blocks.